# Empathy fails to show any contacts, accounts say status is set to offline when it isn't

Tags: startup, empathy

When I start Empathy absolutely no contacts appear, including if I check to show offline contacts.

My accounts are set up and authenticated and yes - I do have contacts on both accounts. When I check the accounts page both of them say "Offline -- Status is set to offline" despite the fact I have manually set my status to Available.

If I uncheck "Enabled" for the account and then re-enable it it connects fine, but it seems when empathy first starts up it's incapable of doing that itself.

Anybody got any suggestions? I'm using a fresh 32bit install of 10.10 with all updates installed and GNOME 2.32.

Comment: Have you tried purging the `~/.config/empathy` directory and starting over with configuration from scratch?

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem in Ubuntu 11.10 with the GNOME Shell.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using autologin? Maybe https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/empathy/+bug/558872
Does quitting and restarting empathy fix the problem? I think that is also a bug.